# What is a better way to convert a simple sinatra app to static html pages?

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra

A friend of mine asked to create a static website and I found that making such site using Sinatra is a pure joy. I just wrote all my routes like this:

```
get '/index.html' do
  haml :index
end

get '/app.css' do
  sass :app
end
....
```

So I was able to use layouts, and haml and sass to put site together quickly.

To create the static site I used

```
wget -r -l2 http://localhost:4567
```

Which did work pretty well, but I imagine there is a better way to create a static site from a Sinatra code?

Comment: does this grab background images for you? or do you need to write routes for them too? wget is not 'getting' background img's referenced in my sass files.

Comment: yes, in my case it did work for style bg images as well

Comment: http://stasis.me/ seem to be another neat way for sinatra > static html conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Httrack](http://www.httrack.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Try `sinatra-export`, an extension made exactly for this purpose with Sinatra :

https://github.com/hooktstudios/sinatra-export

See also this project generator for dealing with assets too :

https://github.com/hooktstudios/sinatra-static-bp

Answer (score 0):

Try [StaticMatic](http://staticmatic.rubyforge.org/).